# AWS Linux, Docker container getting npm to start

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, amazon-ec2, npm

Trying to get docker up and running on a single node to run my javascript app.

Found this AWS article to install npm: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Ran the following commands:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.6/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 6.11.5
node -e "console.log('Running Node.js ' + process.version)"
```

Then started to follow this guide to create an app to test with:
https://medium.com/@sunnykay/docker-development-workflow-node-express-mongo-4bb3b1f7eb1e

I ran:

```
npm init
npm install --save express
npm install --save nodemon
touch app.js
nano app.js

#contents of app.js

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send("Hello World");
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
# add the following to package.json scripts section
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
```

Errors Im getting are below....

```
npm start
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.62-21.56.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/node" "/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.5/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.5
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/ec2-user/docker-node-mongo/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: what is the content of your `package.json` exactly?

Comment: package.json  

   "name": "docker-node-mongo",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "app.js",
   "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.16.2",
  "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
   }
 }

Comment: Its funny when u see your mistake clear as day... I didnt add the start script which clearly its erroring on. Guess I needed more coffee at 6am.   Working through this now. Thx!

Comment: Would suggest to delete the question, as it really doesn't add value to others